# Access execution context metadata in regular providers

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I'm using nestjs for a simple HTTP rest API, with typeorm.
I have 2 Postgres databases, and I want to be able to access both, But it doesn't have to be at the same time.

Basically, I want to set which db an endpoint will use, preferably with a decorator like `SetMetadata`.

Here is my controller:

```js
@Get('/posts')
@SetMetadata('DB_HOST', 'localhost')
async getPosts(): Promise<Posts> {
  return this.postService.getPosts()
}
```

My module looks like this:

```js
Module({
  controllers: [
    AppController,
  ],
  exports: [ConfigModule],
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
                                      /* Can't find this token */
      inject: [ConfigService, Reflector, ExecutionContext],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService, reflector: Reflector, executionContext: ExecutionContext) => {
        return {
          ...config.getPostgresConfig(),
          entities,
          synchronize: true,
          type: "postgres",
          host: reflector.getAllAndOverride('DB_HOST', [executionContext.getHandler(), executionContext.getClass()])
        } as PostgresConnectionOptions;
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I can't find a way of getting the execution context outside a gurad or an interceptor.

Is there a way?

If not, Is there another way I can mark an endpoint and get the value in a provider?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make your `TypeOrmModule` to be [`REQUEST` scoped](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#request-provider) so that it can change which provider (which database) is being accessed based on which URL is being hit.

There's no injection token for the `ExecutionContext`, so you can't check which route handler will be activated via the DI factory, but you could have a URL map which maps URLs to which database they'll use.

You can also use the new [durable providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#durable-providers) feature to only create the database once and keep it memory rather than having to create a new connection each time.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I agree durable providers sound good for this. My problem with the URL map is that it can get out of sync if i rename an endpoint.